# Makefile stops running at the middle

Tags: makefile

I have written the Makefile below to test my learning of makefiles. It makes the paper.pdf file (so, the first set of commands runs perfectly) and then it stops. When I delete the first set of commands, the test.pdf is created and the whole thing runs smoothly. The problem is when I run both of them but despite reading, I cannot find the answer. I am using the terminal for the latest version of Lubuntu if this makes any difference.
Thanks a lot for everyone's time.

```
TEXCMD := xelatex

paper.pdf: paper.tex

    $(TEXCMD) $<
    rm -f paper.aux paper.log

test.pdf: test.tex

    $(TEXCMD) $<
    $(TEXCMD) $<
    bibtex *.aux
    $(TEXCMD) $<
    rm -f test.aux test.log
```

Comment: Can you post the Makefile?

Comment: I am sorry, here it is and thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: How are you invoking `make`?  Did you ask it to make both `paper.pdf` and `test.pdf`?  Or did you just type `make` on its own (which would explain it building the first target)?

Comment: When running "make test.pdf" or "make paper.pdf", it works fine. When running "make" on its own so it can make both files, then it creates only the first one and stops at the removal of the auxilliary and log files. From your answer, I understand that if I type "make" without specifying the target, then it is normal to make only the first file. Am I correct? and how do I run make to create all the files? I would like to pass this file to a colleague who does not have any experience with Makefiles (like myself).

Comment: Thanks, indeed, my question was a duplicate of an older question but I don't have any experience to understand that it was the same thing. Many thanks for everyone who took the time to help me.